# Node.js + Joi how to return error with custom HTTP error code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

I started using joi for validation and I want to return a custom http code when there is an error. On their documentation there is [any.error()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anyerrorerr) which allows you to return a custom message and error code.

however I can't find anywhere on where to return a custom http code, and on their example they are only showing an `Error` with a custom message:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    foo: Joi.number().min(0).error((errors) => new Error('"foo" requires a positive number'))
});
```

Comment: You can implement a `CustomError` class which has an additional `errNo` property. And when you check your errors after validation use that `errNo`

Comment: so a class which will accept an error with type unknown, then do validations inside that class (also by using joi, to check the properties of the error). Then return a new error with the same properties of the original error but with different status code. Because I just need to edit the status code, but I will still need the original properties from the original error. I hope I make sense.